# Como puedo usar el visual shader en el Enviroment Sky Godot

Tags: godot-engine

Asi mismo como el titulo lo dice como puedo usar el visual shader en el enviroment sky godot 3.4 en 3D

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> resultado con importando

Por medio del nodo en godot.. es dificil de importar los archivos de por si en gl es godot y graficarlo aun mas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ahora puse algo mas grafico.. es asi de sencillo usar el visual shader en un spatial material u canvas para representar un cielo en godot, hay alguna manera de omitir el viewport o meramente tenemos que importar el shader por nodos para poder dibujar el sombreador en el enviroment de godot? quisiera saber si hay un camino mas facil

Comment: Estoy suponiendo que este no era el resultado que querías. Pero no sé cómo es el cielo que estas usando ni cómo se debe ver. En cuanto a otras formas de hacerlo, tu podrías hacer una caja de cielo (skybox) y no utilizar Enviroment (sería un mesh que sigue la cámara), sin embargo eso no es lo que preguntaste. Y en cuanto a hacerlo más fácil hay unas opciones en la librería de assets que podrían servirte.